# How can I install cloudera manager on my raring 64-bit machine?

Tags: 13.04, hadoop

a n00b here, I was hoping to install Cloudera Manager on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine but it seems only lucid and precise are supported in their repository for Ubuntu distros, How will I be able to do this as easily as possible, please. Or are there any alternative to Apache Hadoop+Pig I can use that is open-source/powerful/easy-to-use than these?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~cloudera/+archive/ppa

Comment: But the link is for intrepid ibex only

Comment: So what? Just try it: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cloudera/ppa` and after `sudo apt-get update` and after `sudo apt-get install hadoop`

Comment: did not work, something about not recognizing the repo

Comment: hey, I'm having the same problem in here. did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. But I guess installing supported distros like precise on my Virtual Machine is the only quick solution for a beginner such as me.